# detailTextLabel and imageView not accessible on table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)  - and I believe therefore Swift 3 - to try to make a table view with cells other than default, and can't seem to get the cell detailTextLabel or cell imageView to be other than nil.

I have set the Deployment Target of the project to 9.0 on Universal Devices.

In the interface builder, I have established Content as Dynamic Prototypes with 1 Prototype Cell.

In the interface builder, I have set that Table View Cell Style as “Right Detail” with an image “animal08.png” and an Identifier of “PlayerCell”.

In the view controller for the table view, in the override func viewDidLoad():

self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PlayerCell")

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell")!
    print(cell.subviews.count)
    cell.textLabel!.text = "Name: " + myNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Ranking: " + myRankings[indexPath.row].description
    let avatarIndex = indexPath.row + 1
    let avatarIndexName = "animal0" + avatarIndex.description
    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage.init(named: avatarIndexName)

    return cell;
}
```

When I run the program on an iPhone 5 iOS 5.2(13C75) simulator, when I get to the “cell.detailTextLabel!.text statement, I get:

“fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value”

Similarly, the attempt to access the imageView property finds nil.

Sure enough, the print(cell.subviews.count) statement reveals that there is only 1 subview of the cell.
I can see no set or get UITableViewCellStyle property of the UITableViewCell other than through the interface builder, or in the init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) initializer.

I believe using the init method defeats the benefits of dequeueReusableCell, and should not be used in this circumstance.

I have read (without substantiation) that the tableview.register method resets the tableViewCellStyle to default.

The above code seems to be identical to boilerplate code on the Apple Developer site and numerous tutorials by a wide range of contributors.

So, how can I access the detailTextLabel and imageView subviews and still use dequeued cells?

Comment: create a custom table view cell having image view and two label or change the style of uitableviewcell

Comment: A "right detail" table view cell does not have a detail text label, and ( it sure about it, never tried it) you cannot set the right detail item (when you set the image view as you did in your code above you set the (also in this confit not existing) image view on the left. Do @Fahad is absolutely right when he suggests to create a custom table view cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the cell style to a value other than `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. Unwrapping isn't necessary as well in this situation AFAIK.

Regarding the other stuff you try:

By the way printing `cell.subviews.count` won't give you any usable value as all subviews in `UITableViewCell` *should* be added (and default subviews are) inside its `-contentView` (cell property).

Also using cells initialised using `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` has no extra drawbacks as you may still use the reusing mechanism as well as specify the required cell style at the same time. Dequeuing actually has more sense when reusing Storyboard-defined cells with attributes specified in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Well I've just tested in Swift Playground and the code works pretty well with all possible cell styles, with no code crash including the `.default` style.

```import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let c = UITableViewCell(style: .value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)
c.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

c.textLabel?.text = "Text"
c.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail"

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = c```